# Constant current LED driver using opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design

I'm trying to design a constant current LED driver and am totally confused!

This is the schematic i end up with:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZigKC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- What's the formula for calculating R1?
- What's the formula to calculate the required low-pass filter
  capacitor?
- Is this how we calculate the current: `output current = Vref / R2`?
- How reference voltage affects the circuit (decreasing Vref to 2.5V)?

Comment: Where did you find the circuit, why did you choose it, and what does the author of the circuit say about it?

Comment: @TimWescott it's originally from [this](https://eositis.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/simple-constant-current-driver-for-a-high-power-led/) article. not sure why i got a down-vote...!

Comment: Why use the LF33CV, C1, and C2? Wouldn't wiring R3 to 5V and adjust to get the desired voltage at the op amp + input work?

Comment: @JoeSz: that's correct, but only if it is a stable voltage as a reference voltage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSzKQ5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The redrawn schematic. This shows the feedback arrangement more clearly.*

> What's the formula for calculating R1?

R1 and C1 are creating a low-pass filter between the base and emitter to help prevent oscillations.

> What's the formula to calculate the required low-pass filter capacitor?

$$ f_{cut-off} = \frac {1}{2 \pi RC} $$

> Is this how we calculate the current: output current = Vref / R2?

Yes. The voltage will rise on the output until V<sub>-</sub> = V<sub>+</sub>. This will occur when \$ I = \frac {V_{ref}}{R_2} \$.

> How reference voltage affects the circuit (decreasing Vref to 2.5V)?

The current will be affected. You need to reduce it anyway. See below.

---

- As presented the circuit will try to pass 3.3/1 = 3.3 A.
- The emitter of the transistor will be at 3.3 V. That means that the collector will be > 3.3 V.
- If 3.3 A was able to flow you would have a maximum of 1.7 V available for your LED and it won't light much, if at all, unless it's an infrared type (as it has the lowest V<sub>f</sub>). In practice (as pointed out by @What below) the current would level off at a much lower value but more than enough to light an LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAiZH3.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. An adjustable current source. Any pot in the 1k to 100k range should work fine.*

Drop the reference voltage to 1 V (for easy maths) and you should get it to work.

Comment: Thanks, where the 1.7V came from? *"You now have a maximum of 1.7 V available for your LED."*

Comment: 5 V supply - 3.3 V across R2 = 1.7 V. I suggest you retract your acceptance (thank you) for a day or two to encourage others to answer. Often you'll gain other insights which may be helpful.

Comment: @Transistor you may want to mention that \$f_{cut-off}\$ should be no more than about 1/4 the gain-bandwidth product of the op-amp, and something like 1/10 would be safer.  Lower than that is if you actually *want* low-pass filtering.  Also, the \$1\Omega\$ value for R2 is extreme; I'd choose a value for R2 that puts at least 100mV across it, or even a volt if the op-amp has a high offset voltage that needs to be swamped out.

Comment: @Transistor your answer, answered my question. you didn't ask for the source of provided schematic and answered the actual question ;)

Comment: "It won't light much, if at all" Sure it will, it's just that the op amp will not be operating linearly. For instance, a current of 1 amp will drop 1 volt on R2, leaving 4 volts for the transistor and LED. Of course, you're not going to get 1 amp, since the 2N2222 won't do it, and the LM358 won't put out enough base current - but you'll still get appreciable current through the LED.

Comment: @What, you are, of course, completely correct. I got hung up on the "try to pass 3.3 A" bit which, obviously, would never happen in practice. I'll fix it up.